# CreateCOMObject doesn't work on home edition

Tags: warning-messages, .netlink

I can call an application named "PinPoint.Plate" with Visual Basic, Python and *Mathematica* version 8 but not with version 9. I can still call Excel though. How can I fix this? This is what I did:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];
NETLink[];
p = CreateCOMObject["PinPoint.Plate"]
```

gives the error:

```
 (* CreateCOMObject::netexcptn: A .NET exception occurred: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {9B7024E3-BD35-11D2-8EE4-0080C70A9C3D} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at Wolfram.NETLink.Internal.CallPacketHandler.createCOM(KernelLinkImpl ml). >> *)
```

Comment: for starters, put a semi between the Needs and the InstallNET.

Comment: I guess it could have to do with the .NET version that is used. Version 9 uses .NET 4.0 while Version 8 seems to use 2.x according to `ShowNETConsole`. I guess that somehow you need to ensure that PinPoint.Plate is registered in such a way that the .NET version used by mathematica sees it. I'm no .NET expert and don't know PinPoint.Plate, so I don't have an idea how to achieve that...

Answer (score 7):

This is apparently a 32-bit COM object, so you need to force .NET/Link to run in 32-bit mode:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
ReinstallNET["Force32Bit" -> True];
p = CreateCOMObject["PinPoint.Plate"]
```

Generally, the only time you need to worry about bit-ness issues is when you are calling non-.NET code, such as a 32-bit DLL via `DefineDLLFunction` or, as here, a 32-bit COM object.

Comment: WOW That was great it now works. THANKS!!! But it still doesnt call the methods quite right.  I explore it a bit more